# react native input height based on mobile height

Tags: user-interface, react-native, platform

In my react native application, when I run it on a 4 inch screen, the InputText is much bigger than a 5 inch screen. What is the reason behind this? How can I avoid it?

Comment: are you using height or flex ?

Comment: Which package are you using for adding the `Text`?

Comment: rajesh, Im using flex here.
@Pritish, its the default InputText from react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your app is always **accessible by default** and the *UI adapts itself to the changing screen size*, therefore, the `fontSize` change.

You can have a look at the [`allowFontScaling`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#allowfontscaling) prop of the Text and decide what boolean do you want to keep.

By default it is `true` as mentioned [**here**](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/53fb5b6cee50f85bc6220231b2fd39fd94b587db/Libraries/Text/Text.js#L117-L121)

```
getDefaultProps: function(): Object {
    return {
      allowFontScaling: true,
    };
  },
```

In order to disable the font scaling, you can set a *global setting* as

```
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling=false
```

in your highest level container.

Comment: Thanks Pritish for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is huge variety of screen sizes in Android. So we have to get phone dimension sometimes and assign calculated height/width, where required.

In ReactNative we can get the device window size by using:

```
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html

Moreover, if you are using `flex` property, you can use it as well to adjust your UI elements height.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for the answer

Comment: If this helps, please mark this answer correct for other to know the work around.

Answer (score 3):

If your are looking for more precise level implementation..

I think you should implement some scaling mechanism to provide responsive components

```
import { Dimensions, PixelRatio, Platform } from 'react-native'
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')

// Sizes based on Google Nexus 5 on genymotion
const guidelineBaseWidth = 360
const guidelineBaseHeight = 592

const scale = size => width / guidelineBaseWidth * size
const verticalScale = size => height / guidelineBaseHeight * size
const moderateScale = (size, factor = 0.5) => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    factor = PixelRatio.get()
  }

  return size + (scale(size) - size) * factor
}
```

now you can call the function

> moderateScale()

whenever you want horizontal scaling

you can call the function

> verticalScale()

whenever you want vertical scaling

eg:

```
{
...
width: moderateScale(200)
height : verticalScale(100)
}
```

this way you can ensure the responsiveness of your react application

Happy Coding !

Comment: Thanks Manzoor for the reply

Comment: Super-useful function! Thank you!